# Задача для Python

Tags: python, математика

Всем доброго времени суток!

Есть следующая задача:

Мак Дональдс продает жаренную курицу порциями по 6, 9, и 20 кусков. Возможно купить точно 15 кусков (если купить порцию из 6 и 9 кусков). Но точно 16 купить нельзя, поскольку ни одно сочетание сумм положительных значений 6, 9, и 20 не дадут в результате 16.

Задача написать фунцию, которая посчитает для любого числа n, возможно или нет купить точно n кусков курицы: 6a + 9b + 20c = n    ////
a, b, c могут быть натуральными числами или 0.

С программированием проблем нет, а вот с математической точки зрения я понятия не имею, как к этому подойти. За любую идею, как это считать, буду очень признателен!!!!!

Comment: Вам не к нам. а на [маткод](http://math.hashcode.ru/). И погуглите «линейные Диофантовы уравнения».

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо за помощь! Решил 2мя способами:

N1: перебор

def McNuggets(n):
    """
    n is an int

    Returns True if some integer combination of 6, 9 and 20 equals n
    Otherwise returns False.
    """
    # Your Code Here
    for c in range(10):
        for b in range(10):
            for a in range(10):
                if n==6*a+9*b+20*c:
                    return True
    return False

Comment: n2: рекурсия

    def McNuggets(n):
        if (n==0):
            return True
        else:
            if ( n<0 ):
                return False
            else:
                if ( McNuggets(n-6) or McNuggets(n-9) or McNuggets(n-20) )==True :
                    return True
                else:
                    return False

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это - математическая задача, а не вопрос программирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего решить тупым перебором. Очевидно, что максимально возможное значение a равно N/6. Максимально возможное значение b = N/9. И так далее. Вот и делаем три вложенных цикла.

Это, конечно, самый наивный способ. Самый изящный, пожалуй, через рекурсию. Задаемся неким a (из приемлемого диапазона), задача сводится к более простой - всего N-a порций, которые надо разделить на две группы, по b и c порций. Чувствуете, куда я клоню? Python хоть и не Лисп, но такое вполне сможет, я думаю.

Answer (score 0):

В конечном счете задача сводится к решению уравнения с тремя неизвестными.
Вот, что мы имеем:

```
6a + 9b + 20c = N
```

Если упростить, то:

```
3(2a + 3b) + 20c = N
3(2a + 3b) = N - 20c
2a + 3b = (N-20c) / 3;
```

Далее ищем такое целое значение "c", чтобы (N - 20c) было числом, кратным тройке. 
Допустим, нашли (либо 0). 
Нашли "с" и теперь получившееся значение (N-20c)/3 заменим, скажем, на "K":

```
2a + 3b = K
2a = K - 3b
a = (K-3b)/2
```

Теперь ищем такое целое значение переменной "b", чтобы (K-3b) было четным числом (кратным двойке). Получаем значение "b" и "a".

Надеюсь, общая идея понятна, потому как лично я не уверен, что описанный в этом виде алгоритм будет работать. Можем, например, найти такое "c", что число вроде бы получится кратным трем, но не таким, чтобы дальше и "a", и "b" состыковались с ним.